# specific ringtone firebase notification xamarin.android

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

How i can force the push notification to run ringtone instead of default notification sound 
is there any way to ovveride the default behaviour for firebase onMessageReceived 
  [image: OnMessage Received not called]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the specific ringtone in firebase notification.

When you use API 26 or later, you would use Channel of Notification. Use the `SetSound` of channel would cover the default notification sound.

Set the Ringtone with `SetSound` method of Channel.

```
channel.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone),alarmAttributes);
```

The whole code of creating channel:

```
  void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }
        var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
              .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
              .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
        {
            Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
        };   
     channel.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone),alarmAttributes);
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

You could download the code sample about Firebase notification from the link below. Do the change with `SetSound` of channel would set the specific Ringtone.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/firebase-fcmnotifications/