# How to play sometimes sound in notifications

Tags: android, xamarin.android, notifications, android-notifications

I have this code to show a notification which is working as far as to show the notification, but when i run this function again, i dont get any sound.

```
 public NotificationManager nm;
 ...
 void ShowNotification(string title = "", string message = "", string header = "", bool notify = false)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                CreateSilentNotificationChannel();
            }

            var text = GetText(Resource.String.Local_service_label);

            // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
            var sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            var msSinceEpoch = (long)sinceEpoch.TotalMilliseconds;
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);
            PendingIntent refreshIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, typeof(LocalService)), 0);

            Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, currentNotId);
            builder.SetContentTitle(GetString(Resource.String.OddEven_Notifications_AlertTitle))
                .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                  .SetTicker(text)
                                  .SetWhen(msSinceEpoch)
                                  .SetAutoCancel(false)
                                  .SetOngoing(true)
                                  .SetUsesChronometer(true)
                                  .SetShowWhen(true)
                                  .SetContentTitle(title)
                                  .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public)
                                  .SetSubText(header)
                                  .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher))
                                  .SetContentText(message);
            if (notify)
            {
                builder.SetVibrate(new long[] { 0, 400, 200, 200 });
                builder.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification));
            }

            StickyNotification = builder.Build();
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O && notify)
            {

                StickyNotification.Vibrate = new long[] { 0, 400, 200, 200 };
            }

            nm.Notify(NOTIFICATION, StickyNotification);
        }

private void CreateSilentNotificationChannel()
    {
        var channelDescription = "SilentChannelForOddEvenNotification";

        var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(notIDSilent, GetString(Resource.String.app_name), NotificationImportance.High)
        {
            Description = channelDescription,
            Name = GetString(Resource.String.app_name),
        };

        // set the channel properties
        chan1.EnableLights(true);
        chan1.LightColor = Color.Red;
        chan1.SetSound(null, null);
        chan1.EnableVibration(false);
        chan1.SetBypassDnd(true);
        chan1.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;

        // finally create the notification channel
        //var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        nm.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
    }
```

i'm running the function ShowNotification() every 5 minutes but if i have the property notify true or false, i don't get any sound, why?

What is the proper way to have a sticky notification that we update regularly and sometimes we want to also have sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning with Android 8.0 (Oreo), it would better to set the sound or the proority in Channel. And use the two ways below instead of `chan1.SetSound(null, null);`.

1. Use the specific ringtone for notification.

   ```
   void CreateNotificationChannel()
   {
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
        // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
        // channel on older versions of Android.
        return;
    }
    var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
          .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
          .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();
    var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
    {
        Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
    };   
      channel.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone),alarmAttributes);
    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
   }
   ```

For more details, please refer to the link below. [specific ringtone firebase notification xamarin.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345876/specific-ringtone-firebase-notification-xamarin-android/62383781#62383781)

2. Use the custom sound for notification.

   ```
   void CreateNotificationChannel1()
   {
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
        // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
        // channel on older versions of Android.
        return;
    }
    var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
           .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
           .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

    var path = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://com.companyname.NotificationChannelsDemo/" + Resource.Raw.Hello);
    var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
    var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
    var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID1, name, NotificationImportance.Max)
    {
        Description = description
    };
    channel.SetSound(path, alarmAttributes);
    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
   }
   ```

For more info, please check the link below. [Custom Notification Sound FireBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62369695/custom-notification-sound-firebase/62382816#62382816)

Comment: Yes but after i have create the channel im displaying notifications every 5 minutes. how i can disable the sound in some of them? in my tests i could either always have sound or never have sound. I want to be able to control when a notification has sound and vibration. i have also try to create 2 channels, one silent and one with sound and pass every time the channel id but it didnt work, the first channel was always used

Comment: Its complex for change the channel on the same notification. How do you judge the notification disable the sound or not? You could create multiple notifications with sound or vibration or someting else. And then display the notification according to the requirements.

Comment: The notify parameter if is true the sound will play. 2 different notifications sounds like a good idea, i dont see any other way around it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the notification payload of the notification there is a sound key.

From the official documentation its use is:

Indicates a sound to play when the device receives a notification. Supports default or the filename of a sound resource bundled in the app. Sound files must reside in `/res/raw/anySound`.

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

In the notification payload either you can use `"sound" : "default"` OR `"sound" : "anySound"`

In your case might be these lines are problematic

```
chan1.SetSound(null, null);
```

---

```
if (notify){
   builder.SetVibrate(new long[] { 0, 400, 200, 200 });
builder.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification));
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but if i remove the setsound(null,null) i think i will have a sound every time, i want the notification to be without sound and vibration usually and some times to be high priority with sound and vibration

Comment: I guess it should be in condition like if(Sound) chan1.SetSound(something, something); else chan1.SetSound(null, null);

Comment: this code you are saying should be in channel creation? can someone do that? i thought that if you create a channel you cannot alter it later like that